# Three.js OBJLoader very slow

Tags: javascript, three.js

I load some models in obj format with OBJMTLLoader, all of them about 8 models some of them about 2.5 MB in size, those modles take very long time to load to the extent that the page craches and press wait many times to load, i run the page on localhost that is very strange.
this is the code:

```
function loadobj(oid){
return function (object){
    var o=farr.filter(function(row){
        if(row.oid===oid){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    });
    for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){
        var ob=object.clone();
        ob.position.x=o[i].x;
        ob.position.z=o[i].y;
        ob.position.y=0;
        ob.rotation.y=o[i].r;
        ob.userData.period=o[i].period;
        ob.userData.id=o[i].objid;
        ob.userData.oid=o[i].oid;
        ob.userData.level=o[i].level;
        ob.userData.status=o[i].status;
        ob.userData.consumedgold=o[i].consumedgold;
        for(var j=0; j<ob.children.length;j++){
            ob.children[j].userData.parent=ob;
        }
        scene.add(ob);
        objects.push(ob);
    }
    alert("loaded"+" / "+oid);
    document.getElementById("sload").innerHTML="Complete" ;
}
}

function setupobjects(){
    var ides=[];
    for(var i=0;i<farr.length;i++){
        var it=ides.filter(function(row){
            if(row===farr[i].oid){
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        });
        if(it.length===0){
            ides.push(farr[i].oid);
        }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<ides.length;i++){
        var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
            if (xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                document.getElementById("sload").innerHTML="All: "+ides.length+" Current Object: "+ (i)+" Percent: "+ Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' ;
            }
        };
        var onError = function ( xhr ) {};
        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load( "resources/models/"+ides[i]+".obj", "resources/models/"+ides[i]+".mtl",  loadobj(ides[i]), onProgress, onError );
    }
}
```

Another question please: what is the best format for load and render THREE js Collada or Obj?

Comment: I removed the files more than 1 MB and still have the same problem, all models exported from SketchUp as obj models, all objects added to the scene except the last one what ever it is.

Comment: i downloaded some models from clara.io in obj format with different sizes about 1 MB and the problem disappeared !

Comment: i download mazda6 model  7MB it loads instantly !! is the problem in SketchUp?